# Expectation of an ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I came across this sub-question as a part of a bigger question, the question itself seems very simple but I'm having hard time figuring out a solution. Just to give a little background, this comes in a problem set in a master degree level stochastic process course.

I was asked to calculate 
$$
\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}E[1/P_t]
$$
Where
$$
dP_t={1 \over P_t}dt+dW_t
$$
and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $P_0>0$

The answer is apparently 0, although I'm not quite sure how to prove this result.

Many thanks.

Comment: Proof: $$\mathrm d\left(\frac1P\right)=-\frac{\mathrm dW}{P^2}$$

Comment: This can be done by applying ito lemma on 1/P, then can we just say the expectation of d(1/P) is negative so its value must collapse to 0 when time goes to infinity?

Comment: Not quite, to start with, d(1/P) is not a random variable hence I do not know what you call its expectation.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean d(1/p) is always negative, so the value of 1/p should collapse to 0.. although I'm not so convinced about this statement ..how do we argue the limit goes 0 from your result? Thanks

Comment: "I mean d(1/p) is always negative" ?? Note that W is neither nondecreasing nor nonincreasing, even locally. What does my first comment tell you about the process 1/P?

Comment: That means the process 1/P is a local martingale but obviously not a martingale (otherwise its expectation is simply 1/P0 and that can't be 0)..sorry for being dumb here..I'm still not sure how to get that expectation